# What does fb: namespace stand for?

Tags: facebook, namespaces

It might a bug in documentation or just me getting it wrong, but in any case I think it is confusing to see several different definitions of the same fb: namespace:

- `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"`

  Given as example [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).
- `xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"`

  Shows up in the generated XFBML code [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

So which one should the developers use?

Comment: Very good question, still poor documentation for this topic on facebook developer. thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 6):

fb namespace is like your application name.

for example if your application name your testapp your canvas url is going to be

apps.facebook.com/testapp/

hope that helps

Edit : In developers screen there is a namespace field my info is about it.

Comment: I've seen this but I don't think it's relevant here - I mean the official fb: namespace

Comment: followed this hint but makes no sense for me

Answer (score 5):

Just asked a facebook engineer (at the mobile hackathon today).

Advise was use the second one:
xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" Shows up in the generated XFBML code here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

As the first one is for fbml which is deprecated.

(If I am wrong this info came directly from a facebook engineer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should now be using

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

This is what is used in the sample code of the xfbml tab of their beta plugins so I presume this is the latest. I've never seen it used prior to your post implying it is newer then the 2008 facebook namespace. See [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/)

Comment: Maybe it's related to deprecating of FBML:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Comment: When in doubt, check what Facebook is doing. They don't use `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">` themselves ([example](https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins)).

Comment: @10basetom this answer is from 2011 which is why it may be outdated. But I would also stress that the best place to look is the docs, not the source of facebook.com itself (I assume that's what you were getting at) as what is recommended and what companies do is not always the same. Especially as they may try new features out which might not be available yet or they may be slow to adopt their own best practice (admittedly Facebook release quite a lot however).In fact I'm not sure you even need this namespace declaration anymore

Answer (score 0):

xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
both are related about open graph protocol
My understanding was that the xmlns attribute allowed for adding
namespace information for tags and for attributes

Comment: Your understanding is right but it does not clarify which of them is the correct one to use. You cannot have two namespace declarations with the same prefix.